# Multiplicity is not valid in Role Code First

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, migration, entity-framework-migrations

**Books.cs**

```
public class Books
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int PublishinHouseId { get; set; }
        public string IsbnNo { get; set; }
        public string BookName { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public virtual Authors Author { get; set; }
        public virtual  Categories Category { get; set; }
        public virtual PublishingHouses PublishingHouse { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Borrowers> Borrowers { get; set; }
    }
```

**Students.cs**

```
public class Students
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int GenderId { get; set; }
        public  int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public virtual Genders Gender { get; set; }
        public  virtual Departments Department { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Borrowers> Borrowers { get; set; }
    }
```

**Borrowers.cs**

```
public class Borrowers
    {
        public int BorrowerId { get; set; }
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateGiven { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateReceived { get; set; }
        public virtual Books Book { get; set; }
        public  virtual Students Student { get;set ;}
    }
```

**BorrowerMap.cs**

```
public BorrowerMap()
        {
            //Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.BorrowerId);
            //Property
            this.Property(t => t.BorrowerId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
            this.Property(t => t.DateGiven).IsRequired().HasColumnType("Date");
            this.Property(t => t.DateReceived).IsRequired().HasColumnType("Date");          
            this.ToTable("Borrowers");
            this.Property(t => t.BorrowerId).HasColumnName("BorrowerId");
            this.Property(t => t.BookId).HasColumnName("BookId");
            this.Property(t => t.StudentId).HasColumnName("StudentId");
            this.Property(t => t.DateGiven).HasColumnName("DateGiven");
            this.Property(t => t.DateReceived).HasColumnName("DateReceived");            
            this.HasRequired(p => p.Book).WithMany(p => p.Borrowers).HasForeignKey(f => f.BorrowerId);
            this.HasRequired(p => p.Student).WithMany(p => p.Borrowers).HasForeignKey(f => f.StudentId);
        }
```

**Next>**
*Package Manager Console*

```
PM> Add-Migration
cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: MvcDbContext
```

**ERROR:**

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Borrowers_Book_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'Borrowers_Book_Source' in relationship 'Borrowers_Book'. Because the
>   Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the
>   multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.
>   **Please help me?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from Visual Studio.
Good luck with.